# MiniTest with Rails Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

What is the equivalent of this [Doorkeeper protected controllers in RSpec](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-protected-controllers) in Minitest?

```
let(:token) { double :accessible? => true }

before do
  controller.stub(:doorkeeper_token) { token }
end
```

I want to test my  with Minitest, currently all responses are "Expected response to be a , but was <401>"

Answer (score 4):

Based on @riffraff answer:

Add `gem 'mocha'` to your `Gemfile` and then `bundle install` (https://github.com/freerange/mocha)

Add some helpers for your tests:

```
# test/test_helper.rb
# ...
require "mocha/test_unit"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # ...

  def sign_in user
    token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.new(resource_owner_id: user.id)
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stubs(:doorkeeper_token).returns(token)
  end
end
```

Use your new helper in your tests:

```
test 'Whatever you want' do
  sign_in users(:one) # here is an example using fixtures
  # Do your get / post / etc
  # Do your assertions
end
```

Comment: And if you get a 403 error from doorkeeper, remember to specific the scope:
    token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.new(resource_owner_id: user.id, scopes: 'public')

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work and this is quite simple once you find the proper way.

I created a new class in test_helper.rb

```
class StubToken
  def acceptable?(value)
    true
  end
end
```

You can then use this class to bypass the token requirement by calling the following:

```
@controller.instance_variable_set('@_doorkeeper_token', StubToken.new)
```

Since the @_doorkeeper_token is define the following code in the Doorkeeper::helpers will resolve to you stub object.

> File 'lib/doorkeeper/rails/helpers.rb', line 21

```
@_doorkeeper_token ||= OAuth::Token.authenticate request, *Doorkeeper.configuration.access_token_methods
```

And invoke you stub acceptable? methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.new(resource_owner_id: some_user.id)
YourController.any_instance.stubs(:doorkeeper_token).returns(token)
```

or if you use a mocking library just mock the token.

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method \`any_instance' for PortfoliosController:Class` any idea what am I missing?

Comment: adding `gem 'mocha'` to the Gemfile solved the undefined method error